# Is there a name for a process object being serialized to move to a worker node?

Tags: distributed-computing

There's a pattern for RPC or distributed computation I've seen a couple times and I'd like to know if there is a standard name for it so that I can communicate it more effectively. I'm describing it using Java terminology, but I don't think it's Java-specific.

1. To submit a job or RPC call, the calling code creates an instance of some work unit, for example, SendWelcomeEmail
2. SendWelcomeEmail has fields which represent its parameters, which are populated by the job submitter
3. The work unit is then serialized with its fields and sent to a worker node.
4. On the worker node, the work unit is deserialized, and then some method on that work unit class is called to execute the work.
5. The results are serialized and sent back to the calling code or persisted in some place.

Stated another way, I'm looking for a name or origin of the pattern that work units get sent to nodes as an instance of the class that has the actual logic implemented in it.

Answer (score 1):

The formal term you are looking for is ["Request-Reply" messaging](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html). This the pattern includes instantiation of a parameter object, or *Command Message*, and submitting it to the worker node. The worker performs the function or query and returns the results to the caller in a *Document Message*.

[image: Request-Reply Messaging Pattern Component Diagram]

The RPC terminology you are using is used in other systems and languages as well, and in many cases is a synonym for this design.

This messaging pattern is prevalent in *Service Oriented Architecture* (SOA), where many focused, scalable, loosely-coupled worker nodes are utilized to distribute tasks across a system. There is also a category of off-the-shelf and open source packages that can be used to implement this messaging called *Message Oriented Middleware* (MOM). Examples of MOM are [IBM MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq), Apache [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to name a few. (The MQ in all the names stand for "Message Queue".)